# Virtualbox Xubuntu resolutions not matching up

Tags: virtualbox, resolution, xubuntu

I can't find an answer for this question so I'll post it.

I have a VM with Xubuntu installed and 'full-screen mode' worked absolutely fine, the clarity was perfect and it was displaying a 1920x1080 resolution on my 1920x1080 monitor.

I booted it up today and it appears a lot smaller than usual with a big box around the screen. Now in full-screen mode, the size doesn't change its surrounding block just goes black.

So after some searching, **I installed Guest Additions** and enabled "Auto-Size guest display".
Now it fills the screen! But everything is tiny. I checked and it now displays a resolution of **2880x1465** which is crazy.

I double checked the Host settings and selected 'hint' and manually set 1920x1080. But if I set the Guest OS back to 1920x1080 it goes small again.

Does anyone know why the guest OS thinks the host is some obscene resolution? How can I set them both to 1920x1080 and have the guest fill my 1080p monitor in full-screen mode?

Thanks!